# Listview with ffimageloading loads shrunken image after navigate away from page and back

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms app, I have a Syncfusion SfListView with an item template that contains a ffimageloading image control.  The list view has an item tapped event that navigates to a details page.  Upon navigating back, I have the list rebinding in the page's onappearing method.  Sometimes, rather most of the time (not all the time) when you click a list item, navigate to the details page, and come back, the list will load with the item that you clicked, but the image in the row that you clicked is shrunken.  I attached a pic.   Here's the relevant code

```
    <syncfusion:SfListView x:Name="CountriesListView" ItemTapped="SflistView_ItemTapped"
                 AutoFitMode="Height"  ItemsSource="{ Binding CountryList }" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <syncfusion:SfListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              ......
            </DataTemplate>
        </syncfusion:SfListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Frame OutlineColor="Gray" Padding="2"  HasShadow="True" HeightRequest="200">
                        <Grid RowSpacing="5" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="10,5">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="AUTO" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!--<Image Source="{Binding MainIMageURL}" Aspect="Fill" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                                            </Image>-->
                            <ffimageloading:CachedImage Aspect="Fill" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                                FadeAnimationEnabled="true"
                                                Source="{ Binding MainIMageURL }" />
                            <Image Source="{Binding ShadowOverlay}" Grid.RowSpan="2"  Aspect="Fill" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

                            <Grid Margin="10,10,10,0" RowSpacing="10" ColumnSpacing="10" Grid.Row="1">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="AUTO" />
                                    <!--<RowDefinition Height="25" />-->
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="AUTO" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="End"
                                   FontSize="25" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" TextColor="#FFFFFF">
                                    <Label.FontFamily>
                                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                                            <On Platform="iOS" Value="HelveticaNeue-Bold" />
                                            <On Platform="Android" Value="sans-serif-medium" />
                                        </OnPlatform>
                                    </Label.FontFamily>
                                </Label>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </syncfusion:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
    </syncfusion:SfListView>


    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        BindData();
    }

    private async Task BindData()
    {
        await LoadCountries();
    }

    private async Task LoadCountries()
    {
        try
        {
            CountriesListView.IsBusy = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Getting countries");

            await vm.RefreshDataAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("Countries retrieved");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                 .......
        }
        finally
        {
            CountriesListView.IsBusy = false;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to re-bind the data?  What happens if you only do that once?

Comment: Hi, I removed the rebinding, and moved it to the page constructor so it only fires once, and the issue still persists. thanks

Comment: I ended up doing a work around and just using a regular image